# Accessing 3rd Party Services With Authentication

Tags: rest, oauth, identity, ws-federation, bearer-token

I have an application which makes calls to external (3rd party) services and was wondering if I can get some help on this.

I am trying to figure out which way to go with a couple of things and was wondering if you had any kind of input and/or experience on how to handle certain situation

1. We want to be able to create an architecture where a service handles third party calls so that the client doesn’t need to have knowledge of which service it’s accessing.  For example, if we have a way to integrate with 3rd party like DocuSign for document signing, the client should just be able to call a service on our end that determines (based upon some credentials, tenancy, etc.) what service it integrates with. I started out creating an interface, however, that still makes the client determine what implementation to instantiate and call and we want to try and separate that if possible.
   a.  Call our “document signing” service with some indication of the client and tenant that we are working with, probably via access token.
   b.  That document signing service will then need to indicate what kind of credentials that it needs and let the client know how to log on to that service. For example, it may want to redirect to an Authorization Server to get an access token to send up to our service to make the call.
2. We also have some offline processing that will need to be done which may call 3rd party services which need authentication, but there is no client to prompt for.  I started going down the route of storing a SAML token and/or user credentials, but that seems very insecure.    Again, being an IdM pseudo-newbie, not quite sure how to handle this (Googling brings up all kinds of options, but most, if not all seem very insecure).  I suppose we can do something with encryption of tokens, etc. to store along with it to then call the appropriate authorization servers when the time comes to run the task and receive the token.

Any opinions on how to properly handle these?

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all you need to consider that you are using third party API calls to do whatever you need to do, so the first thing you need to keep in mind is that you will surely need access token for your users to access those APIs.

So, if you are saying that you can have various third party APIs for one user, what you might want to do is to create an abstract class which has a CALL() method that will be overridden by concrete classes (one for each third party API), for example:

```
public abstract class ApiData {

//Your variables

protected call(String url, //Some parameters) {
//default body
}
```

After this, you can create a class which will override the ApiData Class. For example:

```
public class DocuSignApi extends ApiData {

//Your variables

@Override
private call(String url, //Some parameters) {
// APi call for DOCUSIGN
}
```

This way, whenever you create a user inside your system, you will need to save a list of ApiData for him, for example:

```
public class MyUser {
// All parameters

private List<ApiData> apiCalls = new ArrayList<ApiData>();

}
```

With this, you will have for every user, all Api calls he can access, you can iterate on that list and for each element call the "call()"
 method and it will call the right third party API.

Now, for you third party API login, it depends on each API. Probably, you might want to use one same credential for each API and use it with everyone of your clients (they wont have access to that, you might have this encrypted in your database or somewhere in your code, like a property file). If each client has a different credential in every API then you will need to log him as well on each API and save the third party access token someplace else (Database), and allow him to use that until it expires.

I am also guessing that you have implemented your own log in service for your users. I am not sure if you were asking what is the best and secure way to do this, but if this is the case, I will give you an example. I have plenty of log ins in some projects i have done and what I use is OAUTH login. Basically what you do is request by HTTP header your credentials encrypted, which then you let the user log in or not by checking in your database if login data is correct. If login is successful you create an  access token,SAVE that access token in your database (with the creation date), and return it back to your user, that way you can also have the functionality of expiring the token which is a very good practice.

Hope this helps..

Cheers